# How to extract tables from PDFs while pulling in non-table text section identifiers

Tags: python, pdf-extraction, pdfplumber

I'm working through extracting tables using pdfplumber in Python from a PDF that has mostly-consistent structure between pages.

My goal is to extract each of the 2 tables under each section header (white font highlighted blue) on each page.  See screenshot below for the structure of the PDF.  The yellow highlights are my targeted extractions.

**Challenge: How to set up the code such that it's clear which `extract_tables()` output is associated with each text section header.**
As you can see the section headers and table description are not built into the table but are instead text elements of the page.

- Some pages have 1, 2, or 3 section headers that may or may not contain the desired tables.

  - If the tables aren't present under a section, I intend to ignore that section or populate an empty table.
- Sometimes the section header starts at the bottom of the page and tables don't start until the next page.
- There are not any cases where a table "spills" over to the next page.  So this might ease complexity.
- I can loop through all pages and pull and append all tables of this specified structure together, but without the text section header and subsequent description line, I don't know what each table represents.

**Alternative approach that was unsuccessful:**

- I tried a pure text extraction approach (not relying on extract_table at all), but the null fields in a table (dark gray) were not registering as empty cells, so consequently, Table 1 in the screenshot below incorrectly assumed the $1000 and $20 went under Facility1.  Can this text extraction approach be improved to recognize those null columns as blank?

**Screenshot of PDF:**

[image]

**End Goal:**
[image]

Comment: @KJ your suggestion seems like a manual correction rather than a generalized approach.  How are you suggesting the code to recognize the extent of the offset needed so that it lands under Facility5?  As a second example, if we run extract_text on the last table in the screenshot, it gives "Row1, $1000, $1000 \n" which would again require manual intervention to offset the second occurrence of $1000 to Facility3.  Please let me know if I missed your point.